# Install Drush Launcher on MacOS Ventura on a Apple Silicon (M2) machine

Tags: drush

I know this is not really a Drupal question but rather Drush. Maybe a Mac user can help me.

I installed drush launcher under MacOs Ventura on a Mac M2 by following the [procedure](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher).

Running `drush st` (for example) after `sudo mv drush.phar /usr/local/bin/drush` gives me this error.

> zsh:permission denied:drush

I changed the permissions but I still get the error. Can you give me any advice?

Should we put it somewhere else?

I managed to install it on my previous Intel Mac but I don't remember how I did it. Perhaps the procedure has since changed.

Comment: Don't do this. Please use [DDEV](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/quickstart/). It basically comes with Drush Launcher built in. And everything else you need for PHP CMS development.

Comment: How did you change the permission exactly?

Comment: @leymannx I will try DDEV. I change the permission in terminal with `chmod 755 foldername` or `chmod 777 filename`.

Comment: You can run `sudo chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/drush`, and after that `drush` should work.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/429812/zsh-permission-denied-when-terminal-has-full-disk-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [README](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher) thoroughly. You are missing one step:

```bash
chmod +x drush.phar
```

Comment: I had done this step well (I had not detailed it in the question, sorry) but thanks to your help, I understood, you put me on the track. I was running the `mv` command in a drush folder (`/usr/local/bin/drush`) and not in `/usr/local/bin/`. We had to rename `drush.phar` to `drush` and not copy it in a drush folder. I'm confused, it was so simple. I made this mistake because there was no folder in `usr/local` and I created `bin` and `drush` which was not necessary.